Activating virtual environment makes python disappear?
Screenshot of Visual Studio Code terminal
As shown in the screenshot, python works just fine in Powershell.
I then activate the virtual environment at E:\DrewFTCAPI\ftcapivenv and python is gone. Not just gone, It doesn't run anything and produces no output.
I would have at least expected some type of "python" is not the name of any cmdlet, function, etc... type error, but nothing.
This virtual environment has worked before, on a Debian-based Linux system before I moved the project and virtual environment over to this windows computer.
I decided this was not a duplicate of the numerous other "python virtenv doesn't work" or "unable to activate virtenv" questions because the lack of output is unique, and because this virtual environment has worked in the past.
I discovered this when translating a BASH script to a Powershell (.ps1) script, noticing that the python calls (to other scripts) were not being executed.
Get-Command python produces:
CommandType     Name                                               Version    Source
-----------     ----                                               -------    ------
Application     python                                             0.0.0.0    E:\DrewFTCAPI\ftcapivenv\bin\python

which is the location of the virtual environment.
I'm doing everything in the Visual Studio Code Powershell terminal.
TL;DR Running python, python3, and python3.11 (my python version) when the virtual environment is activated does nothing.
EDIT: Solved by just creating another Virtual Environment. It wasn't worth the trouble and didn't take that long to reinstall my needed packages.

You will need to do some additional debugging and look at the contents of E:\DrewFTCAPI\ftcapivenv and see if it contains a bin directory and then whether that contains the expected files found in a typical virtual environment, e.g. the python.exe executable, as you appear to be trying to activating this under Windows, as opposed to running this under WSL.  Was this virtual environment set up under WSL originally? If so this can't be activated outside of WSL.

"This virtual environment has worked before, on a Debian-based Linux system before I moved the project and virtual environment over to this windows computer." What exactly do you mean here?

if you know /full/path/to/python then use /full/path/to/python instead of python

if you moved project to new place then you have to create new  virtual environment because it may have /full/path/to/python/in/old/place.
